# PHP and Smarty compile delay after upgrading system

Tags: php, ubuntu, smarty, delay

After upgrading my Xubuntu from 13.04 to 13.10 I am experiencing issue error with Smarty and PHP.

Basically Smarty templates are recompiled with 5-7 seconds delay after I edit template.

I compared system time (`date`) with PHP's `date(...)` and timestamp is equal.

`PHP Version 5.5.3-1ubuntu2`

How to fix it?

Example code:

```
require_once 'classes/Smarty-3.1.8/libs/Smarty.class.php';

$tpl = new Smarty();    
// if I edit this template, changes shows up after
// 3-4 seconds which is very annoying
// there was no issue in xubuntu 13.04 / older php version!
$tpl->display('test.tpl');
```

**Edit:**

I double checked is `filemtime` working properly and it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep opcache enabled and set:

```
opcache.revalidate_freq=0
```

The problem is that by default opcache only checks timestamps after 2 seconds, and the smarty compiled templates are generated during the same request so are not checked.

Setting opcache revalidate_freq to 0 makes opcache check timestamps for all files every time, so changes made in .tpl files show instantly.

Edit: I believe this is no longer necessary as of Smarty v3.1.29

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

Acctionaly there was zend opcache enabled by default in the newest PHP supplied with xubuntu 13.10 and this caused the problem.

I had to change php's config:

```
opcache.enable=0
```

Now everything is fine, templates are compiled straight away after the edit.